# Convert Lines of numbers to words

Tags: python

How the input should be like:

```
5 1 2 0 6 7 9 10 8 8 3 4
4 3 9 8 2 6 3 0  7 7 1 9
```

How the output should be like:

```
five one two zero six seven nine ten eight eight three four
four three nine eight two six three zero seven seven one nine
```

My attempt:

```
value = input()

def user_input(value):
    if isinstance(value, tuple):
        return list(value)
    else:
        user_list = value.split(',')
        numbers = [(x.strip()) for x in user_list]
        return numbers


unit_number = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 
           5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten'}

def convert_n_to_w(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        print(unit_number[int(n)])

numbers = user_input(value)

convert_n_to_w(numbers)

My Output:
8
eight
```

My problem:

> How do I make it similar to the example input and output I gave above

Comment: Rewrite `convert_n_to_w` so that it *returns* a single string (using `' '.join( #appropriate comprehension)`  and *prints* nothing. Let the caller print the resulting string.

Comment: Why do you split on `','` when the input is space-separated?

Comment: ```user_list = value.split(',')``` why are you splitting at a ','? Your input shows that there are no commas in the input but numbers are separated by a space. So you should split at a space like, ```user_list = value.split(" ")```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Your code doesn't correctly read in multiple lines -- `input()` doesn't do that. Try instead `fileinput.input()`.

Comment: Your example output seems to be perfectly fine. Input of `8` gives `eight`. Isn't that the expected?

Comment: Also, a user's `input()` can _never_ be a tuple. It's always a string. So the section `if isinstance(value, tuple):` will never be True and can be removed. However, if you set `value = (5, 1, 2, 0, 6, 7)` and directly call the function `user_input`, then it will be needed. But don't use type-checking; if the `value` is already a list, it would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
value = input()

unit_number = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four',
           5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten'}

output = [unit_number[int(i)] for i in value.split(' ')]

print(' '.join(output))
```